# Node.js: event-based comet insted of periodic ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, node.js, chat, comet

Core features of node.js as far as I understood are (also): event-based structure and very cheap "threads" sleeping. So, it may be really good idea (and probably cheaper) to do not create periodic ajax requests, but to hold events like "user A got a new message" and let user's A connection thread sleep until this event happens.

How do you think - what would be cheaper for server (RAM, CPU) to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for pushing data. It really is very good.

Comment: Yeap. That seems to be a really-really great solution for this kind of "event-based comet". At least at a first glance.

Comment: You should also check out https://github.com/substack/dnode and http://nowjs.com/  (both built on socket.io)